# Matching REGEX website url

Tags: regex

Hello i am having trouble creating a regular expression that matches a particular set of urls.

1. http://www.somedomain.com/example/some-other-page/news/?p=12 Fail
2. http://www.somedomain.com/some-page/chat/?p=123 Pass
3. http://www.somedomain.com/example/path/test/chat/?p=12345 Fail
4. http://www.somedomain.com/example/?p=4321 Pass
5. http://www.somedomain.com/some-page/chat/?p=1   Fail

This is what i have so far i have ^http://www.somedomain.com(/(some-page)(/chat)(/?)(\?.*)?) I am not very comfortable with regular expressions

Comment: Start from https://regex101.com/

Comment: What URL structure are you trying to check? Are all pages under http://www.somedomain.com/example/ accepted or are there additional conditions? Same for some-page. I suggest you specify this in the question.

Comment: Wow Thanks @Jalil. That site is awesome! I got the expression i needed from messing around on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I worked it out, and this is what i came up with ^http:\/\/www\.somedomain\.com(\/(?:some-page|example)(\/(?:chat\/\?p=123|\?p=4321))(\?.*)?)

Comment: @inhaler Self answer or delete your question if it is solved, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using  regex101.com. this is the reg-ex i came up with ^http://www.somedomain.com(/(?:some-page|example)(/(?:‌​chat/\?p=123|\?p=43‌​21))(\?.*)?). Thanks